# unixOBC, Golang, Informix, Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, go, odbc, informix

I'm currently trying to ping an informix database,

```
db, err := sql.Open("odbc","DNS=x")

if err != ni { 
  log.Fatal(err)
}

if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
  log.Printf("ping failed %#v", err)
} else {
  log.Printf("ping success")
}

defer db.Close()
```

and I get an error like this...

```
State: "H", NativeError:"-11060", Message:"[unixODBC]["
```

isql works fine, but I'm getting no luck via the alexbrainman odbc driver. Windows also works fine too. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897252/how-do-i-get-python-and-informix-talking-on-linux/36794878#36794878), the python stuff is actually not all the important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a configuration problem. Appearently, odbc.ini has to be encoded in UCS-2 or UCS-4 according to the informix documentation. This turns out to be how the unixODBC consumes the configuration file.

nearing the end of odbc.ini, there is an [ODBC] section, uncomment the UNICODE option like so

```
;
; UNICODE connection Section
;
[ODBC]
;uncomment the below line for UNICODE connection
UNICODE=UCS-2
;
; Trace file Section
;
Trace=0
TraceFile=/tmp/odbctrace.out
InstallDir=/extra/informix
TRACEDLL=idmrs09a.so
```